# How can I get rid of the "Name" field in a profile listing?

Tags: profile

I'm trying to create a membership directory, and I don't want to display the "Name" field, which shows the "sort name".  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked 5 years ago on the old CiviCRM forum, [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=19343.0).

Here's a solution updated to work with CiviCRM 4.6.10:

```
templates/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.tpl 
@@ -59,26 +51,30 @@
     <table>
       <tr class="columnheader">
       {foreach from=$columnHeaders item=header}
-        <th scope="col">
-        {if $header.sort}
-          {assign var='key' value=$header.sort}
-          {$sort->_response.$key.link}
-        {else}
-          {$header.name}
+        {if $header.sort neq 'sort_name' }
+          {if $header.sort}
+          <th scope="col">
+            {assign var='key' value=$header.sort}
+            {$sort->_response.$key.link}
+           </th>
+          {else}
+            {$header.name}
+          {/if}
         {/if}
-         </th>
       {/foreach}
       </tr>

       {counter start=0 skip=1 print=false}
       {foreach from=$rows item=row name=listings}
       <tr id="row-{$smarty.foreach.listings.iteration}" class="{cycle values="odd-row,even-row"}">
-      {foreach from=$row key=index item=value}
+      {foreach from=$row key=index item=value key=field}
+        {if $field gt 1}
         {if $columnHeaders.$index.field_name}
           <td class="crm-{$columnHeaders.$index.field_name}">{$value}</td>
         {else}
           <td>{$value}</td>
         {/if}
+        {/if}
       {/foreach}
       </tr>
       {/foreach}
```